# Build Gradle with Modules so Java does not require arguments to execute

Tags: gradle, javafx, javafx-8, gradle-kotlin-dsl, tornadofx

I am building a TornadoFx (JavaFX for Kotlin) application. I never had a problem running the application with gradle, but building it into a jar and executing said jar has been a struggle.

Through much trial and error, I have found that I cannot simply run `java -jar App.jar`, but instead I have to add the following arguments to add in the proper dependencies for JavaFX `--module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib/ --add-modules javafx.controls`. But I would like to implement this through gradle, so that these modules are bundled with the jar so that it can be distributed and used by others much nicer.

I have tried to add the JavaFX dependencies 2 different ways, but neither worked:

1. Implementing the OpenJFX maven artifacts as dependencies
2. Adding `includeBuild("/usr/share/openjfx/lib")` to `settings.gradle.kts`

Thank you to anyone who is able to help out.

---

Below are all the details of the application and build process:

- JDK 1.8
- Kotlin 1.4.32
- Gradle Kotlin DSL
- Source Code: [GitHub](https://github.com/JTSchwartz/Scratchpad)

Here is my `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
import no.tornado.fxlauncher.gradle.FXLauncherExtension

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.32"
    id("no.tornado.fxlauncher") version "1.0.20"
}

group = "com.jtschwartz"
version = "1.0.0"

val kotlinVersion: String by rootProject
val tornadoFxVersion: String by rootProject

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

application {
    mainClassName = "com.jtschwartz.scratchpad.ScratchpadKt"
}

configure<FXLauncherExtension> {
    applicationVendor = "Jacob Schwartz (jacob@jtschwartz.com)"
    applicationUrl = "https://storage.googleapis.com/jts-scratchpad-bucket"
    applicationMainClass = application.mainClassName
    applicationVersion = "1.0.2"
    applicationTitle = "Scratchpad"
    applicationName = "Scratchpad"
}

dependencies {
    platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion")
    implementation("no.tornado:tornadofx:$tornadoFxVersion")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVersion")
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = application.mainClassName
    }
    from(configurations.compileClasspath.get().map {if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it)})
}

tasks.register<Exec>("deployToGCP") {
    dependsOn("embedApplicationManifest")
    commandLine("gsutil", "cp", "-r", "./build/libs", "gs://jts-scratchpad-bucket")
}
```

And this is the error I receive when `java -jar App.jar` is run without the necessary module arguments:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at com.jtschwartz.scratchpad.ScratchpadKt.main(Scratchpad.kt:126)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: You say you're using JDK 1.8, but your stack trace shows modules which indicates you're using Java 9+.

Comment: Also, if you're using a recent enough version of Java then you might be able to use the `jpackage` tool. You'd build a custom run-time image that includes JavaFX (make sure to use the JMOD files), and then configure it to put, presumably, your code and Kotlin on the class-path.

Comment: @Slaw I just checked, and you're right about running the Java 9+, I've been jumping between version and ran the jar with Java 11. Gradle was using the JDK 1.8 though at the time of build, I know that for certain. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade past version 1.8 given other library requirements

Comment: The JDK version 1.8 from Oracle should include JavaFX, except on Linux I believe.

Comment: I am on Linux, hence having to manually add the modules

Comment: Still, if you're using Java 8 then modules don't exist. That means you should be getting unrecognized option errors for `--module-path` and `--add-modules`. Also, JavaFX 9+ (the modularized versions) would fail to work on Java 8 due to being compiled by newer versions of Java. In other words, if you're using Java 8 then you should be installing OpenJFX 8. And then you might just have to require that JavaFX is installed before end users can use your application.

Comment: However, since you are (should be) using Java 8 and JavaFX 8, you could make a so-called fat/uber JAR file.

Comment: “jar so that it can be distributed and used by others much nicer” -> I don’t understand how targeting a pre-installed Java 8 runtime could be nice for your users.  I mean, it is difficult for you to even understand why you can’t get such a configuration working yourself, let alone requiring an app user to correctly self-install an obsolete runtime just so they can run your app.  For most users a better solution is to build your app with Java 17, bundling the runtime with your app, packaged into a native installer using jpackage.  That will take some work for you to achieve.

Comment: The FxLauncher plugin relies on Java 1.8 and handles native installer creation, deployment, auto-updating, etc

Comment: @Jacob yes, in that case. that would be another option if sticking with Java 8 is a requirement.